# Appgyver Supersonic List not full width

Tags: appgyver, supersonic

Has anybody had the same problem when settting a list div it would display as an inset list instead of a full width list as shown on the website?

```
<div class="list" >
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: Have you been able to inspect using Safari debugger or Chrome dev tools (depending on the device you are targeting) and see what is causing it?

Comment: I actually figured it out.. it was quite a stupid mistake of mine... I still had a padding class wrapping my list  :S Thank you for your answer anyway! :)